# Keeping all tensors in GPU when training a faster RCNN

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I am trying to train a faster-RCNN model for bounding box detection on a custom COCO-like dataset. I am using a GPU, even though I use `.to(device)` to push tensors into the GPU, I keep getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1845     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight):
   1846         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1847     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1848 
   1849 

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking arugment for argument mat1 in method wrapper_addmm)
```

**Training snippet:**

```
# Initialize Dataset
train_dataset = TrainDataset('coco_train.json')

def collate_fn(batch):
    return tuple(zip(*batch))

train_data_loader = DataLoader(
    train_dataset,
    batch_size=2,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=2,
    collate_fn=collate_fn
)

device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=False)
model.to(device) # EDIT


num_classes = 3 # eyelids, iris + background

in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)

params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=0.005, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=3, gamma=0.1)
num_epochs = 40

itr = 1

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for images, targets in train_data_loader:

        images = list(image.to(device) for image in images)
        targets = [ { k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items() } for t in targets ]

        loss_dict = model(images, targets)

        losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
        loss_value = losses.item()

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        losses.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if itr % 50 == 0:
            print(f"Iteration #{itr} loss: {loss_value}")
        
        itr += 1
        lr_scheduler.step()
```

**My Dataset **getitem**() snippet:** (truncated)

```
def __getitem__(self, index : int):
    ...
    
    target = {}

    target["boxes"] = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
    target["labels"] = torch.as_tensor(labels, dtype=torch.int64)
    target["image_id"] = torch.as_tensor([ int(image_id) ], dtype=torch.int64)
    target["area"] = torch.as_tensor(area, dtype=torch.float32)
    target["iscrowd"] = torch.as_tensor(iscrowd, dtype=torch.int64)

    image = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()(image)
    return image, target
```

Answer (score 0):

You should load your model on the GPU device as well:

```
model.to(device)
```

Note, [`torch.nn.Module.to`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.to) is an inplace operation.

Comment: Getting this now: (Added this line below my where I defined my model)
`RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking arugment for argument mat1 in method wrapper_addmm)`

Comment: updated my question based on your suggestion

Comment: You seem to have replaced a part of your model. It's best if you call `.to(device)` *after* you have performed all manipulations on your model and are ready for inference. Try to call `model.to(device)` after this line: `model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)`.